# Which XAMPP version to choose

Tags: osx, php

I've upgraded my server's PHP from PHP-5.6 to PHP-7.2. I'm ready to download and install an upgraded XAMPP version. I'm currently using very old XAMPP 5.6.31-0.

On XAMPP's site, there are two versions for "7.2.17/PHP 7.2.17." The sizes differ, while "What's included" appears identical.

Why might I choose the 306 Mb file instead of the 145 Mb file?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I am curious as to why you would want to use XAMPP. It’s great for Windows, but OSX is just a GUI over BSD Linux which already has, or can easily install, Apache, MySql and PHP. Sorry that this doesn’t answer your question, but it might provide an alternative

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, Mawg. Which might you recommend I use for Mac OS X?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a mac.I can Google, but soc an you. If you can open a terminal/command line, just type PHP, Mysql and see hat happens. If you get an error, the BSD package manager is `pkg`, so something like `pkg install php` (Search for exact details). Ototh, while that might be "better" or purer, if you are used to XAMPP, stick wiht it. I use it on Windows. Doesn't the XAMPP home page or FAQ tell you?

Comment: Hi, Mawg: I learned that the larger capacity XAMPP version of the same file serves the needs of "XAMPP VM" users, of which I'm not one. So I installed the smaller (145 Mb) version of XAMPP's "7.2.17/PHP 7.2.17" and it works well. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Glad you found what you wanted :-)